# Launch concurrent dependent queries to an API

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, reactive-programming, future

I need to launch several queries to an API from a Java application.
Some of those query depends of the result of the previous ones.
I want each query to be executed as soon as possible (ie. as soon as the required data from the previous query has arrived).

Here is the serial algorithm :

```
var results = new ArrayList<Result>();

var mainItems = api.getCustomerMainItems(customerId); // request A

for(var mainItem : mainItems) {

    var mainItemDetail = api.getMainItemDetail(mainItem.getId()); // N x request B

    var subItems = api.getSubItems(mainItem.getId()); // N x request C

    for(var subItem : subItems) {

        var subItemDetail = api.getSubItemDetail(subItem.getId()); // N x M x request D

        var result = new Result();
        result.setA(mainItem.getA();
        result.setB(mainItemDetail.getB();
        result.setC(subItem.getC();
        result.setD(subItemDetail.getD();

        results.add(result);
    }
}

return result;
```

As we can see :

- the request A has to be launched first and we have to wait for it's result
- for each element of A response we can launch the queries B and C
- for each element of C response we can launch the query D
- once we have the responses of the queries B and D (related with the same mainItem) we can create a result to add to the final results list.

I've tried to use parallelStream, ConpletableFuture and ReactiveFlux but I've failed to find an implementation that can insure that the queries will be launched as soon as possible.

My parallelStream implementation solves the problem partially :

```
List<MainItem> mainItems = api.getCustomerMainItems(customerId); // request A

List<Triple<MainItem, MainItemDetail, SubItem>> subItemsTriples = mainItems.parallelStream()
    .flatMap(mainItem -> {

        var mainItemDetail = api.getMainItemDetail(mainItem.getId()); // N x request B

        var subItems = api.getSubItems(mainItem.getId()); // N x request C

        return subItems.stream().map(subItem -> Triple.of(mainItem, mainItemDetail, subItem))
    })
    .toList();

List<Result> results = subItemsTriples.parallelStream().map(triple -> {
    var mainItem = triple.getLeft();
    var mainItemDetail = triple.getMiddle();
    var subItem = triple.getRight();

    var subItemDetail = api.getSubItemDetail(subItem.getId()); // N x M x request D

    var result = new Result();
    result.setA(mainItem.getA();
    result.setB(mainItemDetail.getB();
    result.setC(subItem.getC();
    result.setD(subItemDetail.getD();

    return result;
}).toList();
```

It allows the queries B+C to be launched simultaneously for each result of A.
It allows the queries D to be launched simultaneously but only once we have all the responses of all B and C queries.

I don't think that the parallelStream() can solve this issue completely but I'm a bit lost with the Future and the Flux framework ...

What framework would you advise ?
Do you have a related example or even better, could you rewrite my code in an optimized asynch way (with the framework that you would advise) ?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a full answer, but I wanted to share my thoughts on this interesting problem:

I would create a worker queue that blocks as long as there are no tasks to process. Each task to process should be started in a separate thread (maybe from a thread pool, but it should be implemented in a way that more than one thread is possible in parallel.)
"add" a task to the queue means to add it to the end of the queue.

First add a task to send request A that waits for the answer. The handling of the answer should add tasks into the worker queue: one to send request B together with a future to fill in the result and one to send request C (with that same future to read it out).

The result handling for request C adds a task to send request D and passes on the future where B will provide the result.

The result handling for request B completes the given future.

The result handling for request D waits for the future and computes the result to fill in the final result list.